# loading external URL working local but not on server

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm Using phonegap to develop a application it was going good and till I move it to my server, I installed phonegap on the server and using phonegap application on ios and android by running the command:

```
$phonegap serve
```

In my app im connecting via ajax to an API i've created on an external url, using the phonegap app on the mobiles when i connect to my local my app pulls through the api data but when i connect to my server and try the same thing it does not connect to my api. In the console on my local when it connects to the api the following comes up

```
[phonegap] 200 /proxy/http%3A%2F%2F
```

and it works fine, but on my server that does not come up both local and my server are running the same app the code is the same.

has anyone got any idea what it can be.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following to your php file

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```